# How to implement a competing consumer patter with rebus on msmq

Tags: msmq, servicebus, rebus

Is there any way to implement a competing consumer patter on MSMQ with Rebus ?

I was hoping to just have consumer point at a single remote queue, but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MSMQ queues are local on a machine, and since transactional remote receive is pretty inefficient, there's no point in doing real competing consumers with MSMQ.

This is also why configuring a remote queue as an endpoint's input queue is simply not possible with Rebus.

What you can do, is to use Rebus' transport message routing capabilities and insert a router, which will function as a round-robin load balancer, to forward messages to the individual workers (which are then free to run on other machines).

Your starting point could be something like this (where `queue` is simply the current name of the input queue):

[image: producer and consumer with single queue]

Without changing anything in Producer, you can install a Router to receive messages from `queue`, using the aforementioned transport message forwarding capabilities to forward each message to one of the consumers:

[image: producer and multiple consumers with router in the middle]

The Router could then be implemented with something like the following piece of code:

```
var consumerQueueNames = new [] {
    "worker1",
    "worker2",
    "worker3"
};

var currentConsumerIndex = 0;

Configure.With(...)
    .Transport(t => t.UseMsmq("queue"))
    .Routing(r => {
        r.AddTransportMessageForwarder(async transportMessage => {
            var index = Interlocked.Increment(ref currentConsumerIndex) 
                        % consumerQueueNames.Length;

            var destination = consumerQueueNames[index];

            return ForwardAction.ForwardTo(destination);
        });
    })
    .Start();
```

I hope this gave you enough inspiration to implement load balancing with Rebus and MSMQ :)